# SharePoint Json Formatter, Not able to change the color of border of the tiles for a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, tiles

I am currently working on JSON formatting of a SharePoint list Tile view and I have a requirement of the custom colour of the border of the tiles. Using this code, but it is not valid as per the list JSON formatter.

Please help Me out.

Thanks In Advance.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": "true",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "tileProps": {
    "hideSelection": true,
    "width": "250",
    "height": "190",
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "flex-direction": "row",
        "padding": "20px",
        "margin-bottom": "16px",
        "max-width": "250px",
        "border-radius": "8px",
        "border-color": "black"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-red--hover"
          },
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-wrap": "wrap",
            "min-width": "20px",
            "min-height": "250px",
            "margin-right": "10px",
            "margin-top": "10px",
            "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "border-width": 6px,
            "border-color": "red"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "img",
                  "attributes": {
                    "src": "[$ComLogo]"
                  },
                  "style": {
                    "width": "150px",
                    "height": "90px"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "a",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listpadding ",
                    "href": ""
                  },
                  "txtContent": "ViewCaseStudy"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listpadding ",
                    "style": {
                      "padding-left": "8px",
                      "white-space": "nowrap"
                    }
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$CustomerName]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listpadding "
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$ProductAndService]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listpadding"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$Country]"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check the border-width in first children->style,the 6px missing quotation marks

Comment: @amos_MSFT thank you for helping me on my silly mistake  

Comment: Did the modified json take effect?

Comment: Yes, Perfectly, adding " " resolved.